# need to connect a new repository to a directory in an existing one

Tags: git

I have a repository, that contains a directory:

```
repository/libs/somelibrary
```

this directory is now to be separated into a different repository but, while this process is going on, my team will keep commiting changes to this directory.
So I created a new repository - `somelibrary` - which will contain the original files like so:

```
- somelibrary
   - src
       - the original directory structure
   - package.json
   - Gruntfile.js
```

What i'm looking is for an easy way to keep that src directory in sync with the commits in the original repository:

```
somelibrary/src/** => repository/libs/somelibrary/**
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a good application case for [subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). First add the original `repository` as a remote to `somelibrary`:

```
git remote add original repository
```

Then fetch it:

```
git fetch original
```

Then initiate a merge of the original repository into `somelibrary`:

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit original/master
```

Only import the correct subtree into the pending commit:

```
git read-tree --prefix=src/ -u original/master:libs/somelibrary
```

Then finalize the commit with `git commit`

Comment: This barely qualifies as an answer. Please consider adding some detail, ideally with specific commands for the OP's situation.

Comment: after the read-tree operation i get:  error: Entry 'src/changedfile.js' overlaps with 'src/changedfile.js'.  Cannot bind.