# filtering commits, after a sub-tree merge

Tags: git

This is a follow-up to this question:

[need to connect a new repository to a directory in an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950463/need-to-connect-a-new-repository-to-a-directory-in-an-existing-one)

Before doing the git commit, I have the original structure from the my original repository + the `src/` directory that is mapped to the libs/somelibrary.
After `git rm -rf` everything except the `src/` i do the `git commit` and everything works out fine.
I have tested pulling new changes from the original repository, again, it works.

My problem:
All the commit log of the original repository is applied to this one; is there a way i end up only with the logs for that specific somelibrary? like if i was doing:

```
git log src/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would probably be to filter commits before doing the sub-tree merge with:

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter libs/somelibrary --
```

in the original repository (or a clone of it just to make sure you won't lose anything in the process).

Note that the subsequent sub-tree merge will be even simpler after this, since after the `filter-branch` operation, the content of `libs/somelibrary` will be at the root of the original repository.

Comment: but that way, i will ruin my original repository, or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes it is a destructive operation. Also, since it is rewriting history, the rewritten commits will have different ids after that.

Comment: well, anyways, it will solve my final problem when this migration is over, so it's really good to know

Comment: I am not sure what your requirements are exactly. But have you looked at the recent [git subtree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) command. It can basically do the same but it is better at dealing with repeated merging. Let me know if it looks promising.

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/) is an article which does a good job at explaining the two-way process between the original repository and the extracted sub directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65041/discussion-between-thibaut-and-andre-alcada-padez).